# My Ip changes Dynamically How can I get updated with the latest ip?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, raspberry-pi, server

My isp provides dynamic ip addresses.I have forwarded my port to an raspberry pi and accessing it through ssh and also using it as web server.but the problem is that ip changes every 3-4 days is there any way or script so that i can be informed or updated with new ip address.
Thank You.

Comment: You didn't specify what device gets the public IP. Try to setup DDNS on it and connect to hostname instead of IP address.

Comment: my Net gear router is connected to the public ip.The router is port forewarded to raspberry pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a script like:

============

```
#!/bin/bash
OUT=$(wget http://checkip.dyndns.org/ -O - -o /dev/null | cut -d: -f 2 | cut -d\< -f 1)
echo $OUT > /root/ipfile
```

============

Set a cron to execute this every 3h or something and configure your mta to send the file /root/ipfile to your email address ( that too you can use a cron ). mutt can be a useful tool to attach the file and do the email delivery.